# explanation of lambda expression in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

I was wondering if anyone could explain this lambda expression and how the output is derived.  I put it into the interpreter and am getting `((2) 2)`.  I'm just not sure why it's giving me that instead of just `(2 2)`.

```
 ((lambda x (cons x x)) 2)
```

Comment: This is a function that always returns `6`. Please show some surrounding code.

Comment: my appoligizes, had the wrong line attach to clipboard, updated the line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `(lambda x (cons x x))` produces a function; the function puts all arguments into a list `x`; the function returns `(cons x x)`.

Your expression calls the above function with an argument of `2`.  In the function `x` is `(2)` (a list of all the arguments).  The function `(cons '(2) '(2))` returns `((2) 2)`

Comment: why does one have (2) and the other is just 2?

Comment: Because `(cons thing '(2))` produces `'(thing 2)`.  Essentially `cons` is for extending a list.

Comment: i still don't quite understand what is going on, sorry.

Comment: Here (http://bit.ly/10xnCcb) is a reference explaining `cons`.  Trying... `'(2)` is a list of one element; `cons` extends lists.  So `(cons thing '(2))` produces a new list of `'(thing 2)`.  In your case, `thing` is `'(2)` so the new list is `'((2) 2)`.

Comment: Ok, Its starting to make more sense whats happening now, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
(cons x x)
```

is not the same as

```
(list x x)
```

since it produces dotted pairs, e.g. `(cons 2 2)` returns `(2 . 2)`.

But when the right side of a dotted pair is a list, the whole thing is a list. `(lambda x expr)` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, puts them in a *list* `x`, so that's `(2)` here. The dotted pair `((2) . (2))` is printed as `((2) 2)` per Lisp conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you've ran off the deep end of scheme.

You've stublled across the notation that allows you to write a function that accepts zero or more arguments. (any number really)

```
(define add-nums
 (lambda x
  (if (null? x)
      0
      (+ (car x) (apply add-nums (cdr x))))))

(add-nums 1 87 203 87 2 4 5)

;Value: 389
```

If you just want one argument you need to enclose x in a set of parenthesis.

And you want to use

(list x x)

or

(cons x (cons x '())

as the function body, as a properly formed list will have an empty list in the tail position.

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to write:

```
((lambda (x) (cons x x)) 2)
```

(note the brackets around `x`).